# Can I use a 220V incadescent bulb to drain a 12V battery?

Tags: batteries, voltage

I'm about to replace the batteries of my UPS. For safety, I'd like to drain the old batteries completely before disposing, but I don't have a large 12v load at my disposal.

Can I wire it to a 220V incadescent bulb (a.k.a. a 'lamp') to drain it?

Comment: You might be better off using a car headlamp as it would drain the battery faster.

Comment: Well I don't have a car headlamp lying around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. The current will be higher than at 230V (230, not 220) though, because the lower voltage won't heat the filament as much as the 230V would. And a less hot filament is a lower resistance (the filament is a PTC resistor).

Comment: As a follow-up, do you think it's a good practice to use a lamp for this purpose?

Comment: @Dave - I think it is. Shorting would be an alternative, but this could cause a high pressure inside the cell. A bulb is a good idea if you don't have a low-resistance power resistor at hand. Or you could use a higher resistor value and leave the battery connected for a looooong time.

Comment: Actually the bulb current will be lower at 12V than at 230V.  The relationship is non-linear but still monotonic.  Think of it this way, if the current were higher it would heat the bulb to a higher temperature than 230V would.  The steady state *has* to be lower.

Comment: @OLin - A 60W bulb draws 0.25A at 230V. Same current at 12V would mean the bulb consumes only 3W. I haven't tested this, but my gut feeling says the filament doesn't heat enough to represent a 50\$\Omega\$ resistance. Heck, I *can't* even test it; all my 60W incandescent bulbs have been replaced with CCFLs!

Comment: But think of driving the bulb with a 250mA current source.  If what you are saying is true, then the voltage will get stuck at 12V.  This means a bulb exhibits hysteresis if true.  Is that really the case?

Comment: Incandescent bulbs, especially high-temperature ones, have a resistance which increases greatly with temperature.  One of the reasons that bulbs are prone to failing at the moment they're powered on is that thin spots will heat up faster than thicker spots.  If a thin spot is hotter than the rest of the filament, it will receive a disproportionate amount of power, causing it to heat up faster still.  Some old projector bulbs (e.g. DJL) have a low-temperature filament, not used for illumination, in series with the main filament, to help limit inrush current.

Comment: @Olin - I almost fell for your hysteresis argument, but I don't give up that easily :-). I'm beginning to wonder if there can't be a hysteresis. Couldn't the current at 12V be different whether you come down from 230V, or increase the voltage from zero? Frankly, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not really sure either, but I think eventually the bulb will stabalize to the same operating point for any fixed current or voltage regardless of previous history.